# How to group multiple objects for purpose of rotating them as a unit?

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, 3d, transformation

I need some pointers on the best approach for a rotation task in OpenGL.  I know how to rotate objects in 3D space using quaternions, I can translate them, all well and good.

But I want to know the best way to treat a collection of different objects as a single entity for the purpose of rotation. For example, suppose you have a desk with objects on it. Each has its own translation and rotation, but now I want to rotate the entire desk and everything on it, while keeping other objects in the room in place. This means objects on the outer edge of the desk will rotate and also translate around the center of the desk, while objects at the center might just rotate but otherwise stay in place, or simply not translate by as much, depending on their distance from the axis of rotation.

It seems that a rather inelegant way to do this is to individually rotate and translate each object on the desk, as well as the desk itself, knowing where the axis of rotation is. Perhaps this is the only good way to do it, but is there a technique to "group" disparate objects for this purpose?

Comment: If you're asking about OpenGL ES, *don't* use the OpenGL tag.

Comment: rotation and matrix techniques in this example apply to both OpenGL and OpenGL ES. What about this question is specific to OpenGL ES?

Comment: By that logic, it's not about *any* form of OpenGL, since any 3D graphics API would use the same techniques. Therefore, it shouldn't have *any* OpenGL tag.

Comment: I'm confused; the content of the question has not changed one word, but you have changed its tags twice, and changed your criteria for how it should be tagged each time. Somewhere along the line has been a downvote for no obvious reason since the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Either the criteria is "what tools I'm using" or the criteria is "who would the answers be appropriate for." In case A, you're not using desktop OpenGL, so it shouldn't be there. In case B, no form of OpenGL should be there, since it's a pure graphics question that's API-agnostic. I'll leave it to you to decide which criteria to use, but neither criteria allows desktop OpenGL.

Comment: I never said I was not using desktop OpenGL. Where did you get that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26694/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-sebby-johanns)

Comment: as per our chat when you say "If you are writing an application that uses OpenGL and OpenGL ES, then you can use those tags based on that reasoning" I will edit the tags to reflect that.

Comment: Note that both answers to this question so far address API-specific solutions, hence offering the benefits of my tagging this with OpenGL and making the answers more effective to my question.

Comment: "*Note that both answers to this question so far address API-specific solutions*" No they don't. JasonD's answer mentions OpenGL once, but only in that it used to have a matrix stack. Datenwolf only mentions OpenGL in that it uses column-major canonical matrix ordering. The actual mathematics and code suggested are ultimately no different from one API to the next.

Comment: I see you want to play devil's advocate but datenwolf's answer about how to lay it out in the matrix order for OpenGL is quite useful. I'm really surprised to see you making such a fuss over the use of tags that are relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for are transformation hierachies. The objects on your desk are positioned relative to the desk, or in other words in the coordinate system of the desk. So lets designate `M_Desk` as the transformation defining the placement of the desk and the local coordinate system of it. Next let be `M_Pencilbox` the transformation of the pencil box standing on the desk in relation to the desk. And a pencil in the pencil box would be placed in relation to the pencil box.

So the pencil goes through a hierachy of transformations. Remember that in the column major notation used by OpenGL things "flow" through the transformation chain from last transformation to first (or right to left when written down).

Each transformation, like `M_Desk` for example, is a 4×4 matrix that can be constructed the usual way: Rotations, translations, scalings, etc.

So to transform the vertices of a pencil you'd apply the following transformation

```
… · M_Desk · M_Pencilbox · v_Pencil
```

Of course the desk itself may be in relation to something different, like a room. At the very beginning of that transformation chain would be the view transformation. So effectively we're building a modelview matrix here.

In terms of modern OpenGL, everytime you encounter a branch in the transformation hierachy (think of directories in a file system), you'd create a copy of the transformation chain built so far, so that you don't have to restart from scratch for each branch.

Let me know if you need further clearification.

Comment: this is very interesting and useful; I need to think about it bit more and try some experimenting and then will let you know any questions. I appreciate the explanation very much.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, can you confirm. Suppose I have transformed the desk, it has a matrix `M_Desk`. Now I want to place the pencilbox on it. In my vertex shader, I only have one uniform for modelview matrix, so I send to that uniform a matrix first created like `M_Pencilbox * M_Desk` -- in that order, as this is in the c++ code not in the shader. After that call, I then take a copy of this combined matrix, let's call it `M_Copy` and apply it to  each pencil like `M_Pencil * M_Copy` and send that to the shader as the modelview before rendering each pencil. Correct?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Yes, but the order should be right associative, i.e. the additional transformation to be applied goes to the right. Of course with OpenGL treating matrices as used by some other libraries as transposed the order may swap (A·B = transposed(B)·transposed(A)); as you probably know matrix multiplication is not commutative (i.e. A·B =/= B·A).

Comment: Hmm, while a vertex shader would do rotation followed by translation as `translation * rotation` since what is on the right happens first, the ordering in c++ code is normal left to right, like `rotation * translation` if you are creating the final matrix in c++ before sending it to the shader, right? in your code snippet above `M_Desk · M_Pencilbox · v_Pencil` were you talking about left-to-right order or right-to-left?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: I'm assuming column major matrices which have right associative multiplication, i.e. the transformation chain goes from right to left. C/C++ by itself doesn't define a certain matrix scheme, since C/C++ doesn't have a matrix type. C multidimensional arrays can be treated as either column major or row major, it just depends in which way one interprets the indices. For example my linmath.h math library uses C multidimensional arrays in column major order and hence uses right to left association, as GLSL does. Flip into row major ordering and you got left to right.

Comment: thanks, i'm going to have a look at your library linmath.h and i might have another question on this topic, but i will ask it fresh

Comment: I have added a new question about your library (and another one) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583343/are-these-functions-column-major-or-row-major  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is generally accomplished by using some kind of scene-graph which incorporates a transform hierarchy.

A simple minimal version would be to have a tree where each node contains an object, a transform, and a list of child nodes. The transform is relative to the parent node.

So the objects on the desk would be children of the desk itself.

The transform for any given object is the concatenation of that object's transform with all its parents in the tree. There are many ways to accomplish that, but the 'old school' GL functionality provides a matrix stack for this purpose. You multiply in the local matrix for a node, draw the geometry for that node, recursively draw all the child nodes, and then pop the matrix back off.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm going to think about this over the weekend.

Comment: As I am using shaders, not the matrix stacks, and I would perform the transform hierarchy in c++ and then send the final transform to a vertex shader, would I instead do something in c++ like your example but with `childMatrix * parentMatrix` and then send that completed single matrix from c++ as a single modelview matrix to the shader

Comment: Yes. However you want to store/process the matrices, the general approach is to have the CPU collapse the hierarchy before passing the geometry and final matrix to the GPU. GL used a stack, I often just store the global matrix in the tree, and/or have a pre-processed array of matrices which can be efficiently filled in and accessed.